# Page cannot be displayed error when using enctype="multipart/form-data" in form

Tags: php, forms, multipartform-data, enctype

I discovered today that both IE and Firefox are giving me an error that the page cannot be displayed when I try to add an article to my site using a basic form (handled by PHP). It was working a week ago, but I have a serious suspicion that the server admin changed the PHP version, because nothing has changed in my code. The code is:

```
<form action="?do=manage&act=article&action=edit&id='.$id.'&submit=true" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
//several lines of code - inputs...
</form>
```

When I delete the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` part, it works perfectly except that the files cannot be uploaded anymore. That's also a problem, because I need to add files to articles, and also this issue occurs in my photo album where file uploading is a must.

Could the enctype part be the problem? Has anybody encountered this issue before?

Here's some information about the server:
PHP API: 20100412 
Apache Version: Apache/2.2.17 (Linux/SUSE)

Comment: `page cannot be displayed error` is not a useful hint. Look into the server logs.

Comment: There is nothing in error log, just some old errors, which I received, when I was debuging the site.

Answer (score 0):

1. You *probably*  have error reporting turned off
2. The error that is breaking your page is *probably* your form action which is not working the way you think it does.

.

```
<form action="?do=manage&act=article&action=edit&id='.$id.'&submit=true" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

should be

```
<form action="?do=manage&act=article&action=edit&id=<?= $id; ?>&submit=true" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say, that the whole form is within php echo, so the variable is not the problem (it acts the same on forms without variables in the action).

Answer (score 0):

I've contacted my hosting provider and they resolved the issue. The problem was in configuration of the server. They updated the PHP version from 5.4.x to 5.5.x and forgot to change the config file to the way it was. So there was no file upload allowed and that's why my page was unable to load.

I hope this helps someone else with similar problem :)